# Use Symfony to authenticate users for external service

Tags: angularjs, symfony, authentication, oauth, ftp

I've been googling the entire afternoon and I'm still not able to figure out what's the best solution to implement the following:

We have build a webapp in AngularJS that consumes interacts with REST API build using Symfony. The app allows users to register, login and do stuff. Now, these users need to upload very big files (>60GB) into their personal folders. A separate VM have been setup for this purpose (data server), located in the same VLAN as the frontend, backend and the MySQL db serving the data. The data upload will be done using either HTTP (using JQuery File Upload plugin) or an FTP client.

I'd like the users to authenticate into the data server (both via FTP or HTTP) using the credentials they already have for the app. For the FTP case, I'll use PureFTP as FTP server, which validates user/pass directly from the MySQL. As far as I know, this is the most convenient solution, but criticism is accepted.
For the HTTP upload, we could proceed in a similar way: POST user/pass, validate against DB and return true/false. Since all the communication will happen within the VLAN, security issues are less problematic. Nonetheless, I believe much more sophisticated solutions have already been developed.

My first thought was to build an OAuth server on Symfony and then authenticate the uploader (and future services) with their respective clients. Is this a right approach or is this a too complicated solution?

Alternatively, a service in the dataserver could validate user's credentials sent by the client against the REST API, receive a JWT and generate a new session for that particular client to list and update files on a particular folder. I'm not sure how to build this middleware though, do I need another Symfony instance or a simple PHP script will do the trick?

Please do not hesitate to share any thought you have on this. Any point of view will be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: try http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: Please correct me if I get it wrong, but what you suggest would allow a given user to query the API directly, without having to first authenticate and receive a session token. That would make no sense on my setup, where I do want sessions for the file uploads, but those should be managed by the service at the data server, which would delegate authentication to Symfony